# how to search k nearest element in database?

Tags: mysql, database, cassandra, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I need to search a record which is **k** nearest to a column value. This table may contain thousands of thousands of records.

How can I do so?

Which Database is preferred and why?

Comment: i voteclosed this question.. "Which Database is preferred and why?" because this primarily opinion-based and also the broad .. Besides most SQL and No-SQL database should support something like this..in SQL it's more or less like `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE column < value ORDER BY column LIMIT k` (MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL)

Comment: Preference in terms of fetching data quickly.

Comment: "Preference in terms of fetching data quickly." way to board to explain.. short answer use indexing.

Comment: The database you and your team have most experience with or interest in. Most can be made to solve this problem efficiently. Consider non-data modeling factors (ie hosting cost, operational overhead, durability, availability needs etc) since this is a pretty simple use case. This will be pretty unique to your organization and project so its too broad for a straight "A is better than B" here.

Comment: MySQL because it's free